# When does a Gridview have a null DataSource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I've read multiple sources that say Gridview's do not persist the [Gridview.DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.datasource.aspx) property on postback.  My understanding is that in term's of ASP.NET, a postback is any page load that is not the first pageload (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx)).

I've got a situation with 2 very similar gridviews.

GvOne.DataSource is null on postback.
GvTwo.DataSource is NOT null on postback.

The only big difference outside of a few differing columns is GvOne is populated with the Entity Framework and LINQ.  GvTwo is populated by a DataTable filled by a SqlDataAdapter.

Further, GvOne and GvTwo have a TemplateField with a TextBox that I use to gather user input.  Both use the same code to pull the TextBox.Text on postback:

```
TextBox tb = (TextBox)GvOne.Rows[i].FindControl("actualTxt");
```

GvOne properly gathers tb.Text.  GvTwo **always finds the tb.Text value to be 0**.

Basic Gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GvOne" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Return">
   <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:TextBox id="actualTxt" runat="server" Text='0' Width="40px"></asp:TextBox>
   </ItemTemplate>      
       </asp:TemplateField> 
         ...
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:GridView ID="GvTwo" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order">
   <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:TextBox id="actualTxt" runat="server" Text='0' Width="40px"></asp:TextBox>
   </ItemTemplate>      
       </asp:TemplateField> 

         ...
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Changing GvTwo to use Entity Framework and LINQ is a potential solution, albeit a major undertaking.  Does anyone know what is going on here?

**UPDATE** (See my comment on Joel Etherton's Answer)
Due to popular demand here is the code to populate the gridview within Page_Load event for GvTwo (GvOne is similar):

```
   ordersGV.DataSource = dataSetObject.Tables["activeParts"];
    ordersGV.DataBind();
```

Searching through the code behind I found no other references to ordersGv.Datasource and no other events that are hooked into associated with the page life cycle.

Comment: This isn't constructive or helpful at all, but I had to point out that your subject sounds like the setup for a joke. Perhaps the response could be, "When the DataSource is ajar!"

Comment: We need to see the code that binds the GridViews (and when - so it's important to specify the page events in which you bind them).

Comment: Regarding the update - we need more than that! The whole `Page_Load` method (minus anything you need to protect) would be a good start. You can make room for it by removing the .aspx markup, which isn't relevant (except to show us that you're not using declarative binding). We need to see if there are any special conditions, what's filling dataSetObject, etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gridviews do not persist the datasource across postbacks. If you have a gridview that has a non-null datasource then you must be filling that datasource somewhere in your code. It would be instructive to travel through your event cycle to find where exactly the population of the datasource is occuring on postback.

Comment: That's very helpful!  The first big issue is solved.  My Page_Load event checks for (!IsPostBack) in GvOne, but not in GvTwo so the GridView is being repopulated on postbacks!  That may also be why the tb.Text values are being reset to 0...I'll give it a go with the check for postbacks and if I just mark as answer then we're good to go!!!

Comment: Indeed.  The simple lack of check for !IsPostback caused all these problems.  Thanks very much for your straightforward answer.

Comment: And this is why I asked you what your Page_Load code looked like.

Answer (score 3):

what does your Page_load code look like?

GridView does not keep DataSource property populated over the postbacks for performance issues

Maybe the second gridview is rebinding the datasource on postback?

Comment: thanks for the -1... without looking at the page load or how you bind your data, it's hard to figure out the problem...

Comment: +1 to counter downvote-without-comment. That said, this probably should have been a comment itself.

Comment: +1 Yes, your comment was helpful to get me towards the answer. In going to get the full code the answer became obvious.

Comment: When you have an issue with data binding in asp.net, it usually (99%) has to do with how you bind the data in the page_load method unless you're using ajax